# Test script failing due to "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" , when I try to automate application. It run fine when test the same flow manually

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, chromedriver

I am using Java. I am trying to automate a scenario, where am trying to search all details of an ID, it works fine when I test the scenario manually. It fails when I automate the scenario.

Note: I was able to successfully automate this scenario earlier.

I am getting the below response when I automate it:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Context creation failed: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80","extensions":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","exception":{"stacktrace":["Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80","    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)"]}}}]}
```

Comment: Whether the testing is carried out in different devices?? Like you are doing manual testing in an machine which is getting passed and automation in another machine which is getting failed

Comment: No same machine, even I cleared the browser cache and also run in incognito  it was success when I do manual .

Comment: It fails if I try manually in the browser launched by driver.

Comment: It seems your application is calling the app running on the port 80 of your local machine. Is this expected?

Comment: I guess your testing with url "127.0.0.1" where port is 80. So your actual url is  127.0.0.1:80. Make a try with your local network link. `192.168.8.1:80` where 192.168.8.1 is your machine ip.

Comment: You can get your ip by `ipconfig` from terminal also post your actual test url here

Comment: Please add information like what are you testing , what's the code , which line you are getting the error , your stack trace ( the error that getting thrown)

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this because I had set capability

:- chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-web-security");

After removing this it's all fine .

Origin was not going in request headers, which is used in facade layer. if undefined then it gets replaced by local.